# I want to capture the declared intention before a specific intention that ends the dialogue

Tags: websphere, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Currently I work in a bank where it has a Watson bot and I need to capture and save the intention prior to a specific intention that generates the derivation with a human. I need to do this to know the last topic the user talked about before the referral with a human

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog that recognises the previous intent should save that intent in a context variable. You can set it to any arbitrary value that makes sense to your dialog.

If you did want it to match an intent, you can set it to the intent eg. where `abc` is the intent you are capturing

`#abc`

If the intent is `abc` then `#abc` is true, else it is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the *intents* in a context variable using `<? intents ?>`

`intents` is an array of objects that have this structure and is sorted in descending order of confidence.

```
[
  {
    "intent":"greeting",
    "confidence":1
  },
  {
    "intent":"yes",
    "confidence":0
  },
  {
    "intent":"pizza-order",
    "confidence":0
  }
]
```

You can find more info about this built-in variable [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-intent)